# http:403 forbidden error for members of the site

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, 2007

I have a SharePoint 2007, there is document Library in its site. I have 3 kinds of users

1. Owner of the site
2. Members of the site (have contributed permission for the site)
3. Visitor of the site

each day morning when a member of site user comes and want to start uploading a file in SharePoint site, he gets the HTTP:403 forbidden  error. this happens until one of the farm users who are the owner of the site comes and surf upload section of SharePoint site. after that, the Members of the site are able to surf upload page and also are able to upload the files.

I found This in Log File

```
      11/16/2016 07:45:09.70    w3wp.exe (0x12D8)                           0x11A4  Windows SharePoint Services     General                         6t8b    Verbose     Looking up context  site http://spserver:80/_layouts/upload.aspx?List=%7BFE3B19AF%2DD80C%2D4538%2D88C3%2D820266F54BFF%7D&RootFolder=%2FDocLib4&ContentTypeId=0x010102003C9E6CB766F73844B183FC79EF3487E8&Source=%2FDocLib4%2FForms%2F2%2Easpx in the farm MOSS_Config     
      11/16/2016 07:45:09.70    w3wp.exe (0x12D8)                           0x11A4  Windows SharePoint Services     General                         6t8d    Verbose     Looking up the additional information about the typical site http://spserver:80/_layouts/upload.aspx?List=%7BFE3B19AF%2DD80C%2D4538%2D88C3%2D820266F54BFF%7D&RootFolder=%2FDocLib4&ContentTypeId=0x010102003C9E6CB766F73844B183FC79EF3487E8&Source=%2FDocLib4%2FForms%2F2%2Easpx.    
      11/16/2016 07:45:09.70    w3wp.exe (0x12D8)                           0x11A4  Windows SharePoint Services     General                         6t8f    Verbose     Site lookup is replacing http://spserver:80/_layouts/upload.aspx?List=%7BFE3B19AF%2DD80C%2D4538%2D88C3%2D820266F54BFF%7D&RootFolder=%2FDocLib4&ContentTypeId=0x010102003C9E6CB766F73844B183FC79EF3487E8&Source=%2FDocLib4%2FForms%2F2%2Easpx with the alternate access url http://spserver.  
      11/16/2016 07:45:09.70    w3wp.exe (0x12D8)                           0x11A4  Windows SharePoint Services     General                         6t8g    Verbose     Looking up typical site http://spserver:80/_layouts/upload.aspx?List=%7BFE3B19AF%2DD80C%2D4538%2D88C3%2D820266F54BFF%7D&RootFolder=%2FDocLib4&ContentTypeId=0x010102003C9E6CB766F73844B183FC79EF3487E8&Source=%2FDocLib4%2FForms%2F2%2Easpx in web application SPWebApplication Name=Default Web Site Parent=SPWebService.   
      11/16/2016 07:45:09.70    w3wp.exe (0x12D8)                           0x11A4  Windows SharePoint Services     General                         6t8h    Verbose     Found typical site / (b8ed3d50-2ba7-4bae-8a4e-14aa2bb858ff) in web application SPWebApplication Name=Default Web Site Parent=SPWebService.   
      11/16/2016 07:45:09.70    w3wp.exe (0x12D8)                           0x11A4  Windows SharePoint Services     General                         8xfr    Verbose     PermissionMask check failed. asking for 0x00000000, have 0x40000000  
      11/16/2016 07:45:09.70    w3wp.exe (0x12D8)                           0x11A4  Windows SharePoint Services     General                         8xfr    Verbose     PermissionMask check failed. asking for 0x00000015, have 0x00000000  
      11/16/2016 07:45:09.72    w3wp.exe (0x12D8)                           0x11A4  Windows SharePoint Services     General                         8xfr    Verbose     PermissionMask check failed. asking for 0x00000005, have 0x00000000  
      11/16/2016 07:45:09.72    w3wp.exe (0x12D8)                           0x11A4  Windows SharePoint Services     General                         8xfr    Verbose     PermissionMask check failed. asking for 0x00000015, have 0x00000000  
      11/16/2016 07:45:09.72    w3wp.exe (0x12D8)                           0x11A4  Windows SharePoint Services     General                         8xfr    Verbose     PermissionMask check failed. asking for 0x00000041, have 0x00000000  
      11/16/2016 07:45:09.89    w3wp.exe (0x12D8)                           0x11A4  Windows SharePoint Services     General                         8nca    Verbose     Application error when access /_layouts/upload.aspx, Error=Access to the path 'c:\inetpub\wwwroot\bin' is denied.   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)     at System.IO.Directory.InternalGetFileDirectoryNames(String path, String userPathOriginal, String searchPattern, Boolean includeFiles, Boolean includeDirs, SearchOption searchOption)     at System.IO.DirectoryInfo.GetFiles(String searchPattern, SearchOption searchOption)     at System.IO.DirectoryInfo.GetFiles(String searchPattern)     at System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAllAssembliesFromAppDomainBinDirectory()     at System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssembly(AssemblyInfo ai)     at System.Web.Configuration.AssemblyInfo.get_AssemblyInternal()     at System.Web.Compilation....
```

can any body help me what could be the reason?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. I just set read/Execute permission for those users who have a problem on this path c:\INetpub\wwwroot\bin

That Solved my problem.
Hope this helps anyone who has the same problem.